# Docker Run upload failed - upload failed because zip_path was not found

Tags: docker

I have a project to do some network tests using `pyats xpresso` dashboard [pyats xpresso](https://github.com/CiscoTestAutomation/xpresso)

and I use Docker image `ciscotestautomation/pyats` to do the test which has Dockerfile:

[Dockerfile for creating pyats-docker](https://github.com/CiscoTestAutomation/pyats-docker/blob/master/21.7/full/docker-entrypoint.sh)

And an entrypoint.sh file contains:
[pyats docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/CiscoTestAutomation/pyats-docker/blob/master/21.7/full/docker-entrypoint.sh)

the problem is:
I created a volume in the ubuntu docker host to upload some test files to the docker container "pyats".

and I got the following Error Details:

> "Run upload failed - upload failed because zip_path was not found."

and the run console log is:

> [Entrypoint] Starting pyATS Docker Image ...
>
> [Entrypoint] Workspace Directory: /pyats
>
> [Entrypoint] Activating workspace
>
> /entrypoint.sh: line 11: /pyats/bin/activate: No such file or
> directory
>
> [Entrypoint] Starting pyATS Docker Image ...
>
> [Entrypoint] Workspace Directory: /pyats
>
> [Entrypoint] Activating workspace
>
> /entrypoint.sh: line 11: /pyats/bin/activate: No such file or
> directory
>
> /entrypoint.sh: line 11: /pyats/bin/activate: No such file or
> directory
>
> [Entrypoint] Starting pyATS Docker Image ...
>
> [Entrypoint] Workspace Directory: /pyats
>
> [Entrypoint] Activating workspace

how to solve the issue, I am a newbie to docker and pyats xpresso as well. and I think the issue is in docker volume if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/CiscoTestAutomation/pyats-docker/blob/master/21.7/full/Dockerfile), when the docker image was created, `Python3 virtualenv` have been initialized in `/pyats` directory inside your docker image. This directory contains some folders and files.

When you create and attach a new volume to `/pyats`, all files and folders installed in `/pyats` directory inside your docker image by the `Dockerfile` will be override with the contents of your new volume. This is why you get:

```
/entrypoint.sh: line 11: /pyats/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

In order to make it running, you may run your docker image without attaching any volume to `/pyats`.

But if you still need to have persistent files in `/pyats` while being able to modify it from your host, you may attach your volume to a new folder inside `/pyats` like this:

Create your host file directory and put your files in it:

```
mkdir myfiledir
echo "print('hello there!')" > myfiledir/testfile.py
```

Mount your host file directory to `/pyats/myfiles` inside your docker container and you may access your files:

```
docker run -it -v $(pwd)/myfiledir:/pyats/myfiles ciscotestautomation/pyats:latest 
[Entrypoint] Starting pyATS Docker Image ...
[Entrypoint] Workspace Directory: /pyats
[Entrypoint] Activating workspace
Python 3.6.14 (default, Jun 29 2021, 21:29:56) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exec(open("myfiles/testfile.py").read())
hello there!
>>> exit()
```

Please note that you may change `myfiles` to other folder name as you like but not `bin`, `lib` or `users` because those directories already exits in `/pyats`

```
ls -l /pyats
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul 29 14:42 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul 29 14:42 lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  225 Jul 29 14:42 pyvenv.cfg
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 29 14:43 users
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot to understand docker volume. but in Xpresso dashboard GUI I can not how to handle these errors, and now I have another error.